# Intellij: Is there an option or configuration to make the "Run Anything" dialog content wider?

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to use the new "Run Anything" functionality of IDEA, but my run configuration names are too wide and I can't differentiate them:

[image]

Is there an option or configuration to make IDEA not truncate the content?

Using IDEA 2018.3